# os.system ubuntu terminal and python

Tags: python, terminal, os.system

When I echo a txt document and my service works perfectly, i use the terminal. Here is the command that works:
echo $(<piece.txt ) | nc 127.0.0.1 9988

When I try to do the same command in python using os.
os.system("echo '$(<piece.txt )' | nc 127.0.0.1 9988")

I have tried all kinds of parenthesis options and different options that wont work.

My preference is to actually echo a string variable. If someone can help me either echo a text doc or echo a string variable it would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you use `os.system()` for that at all? Use the Python `socket` library and you won't have any need for `nc` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that's because `echo $(<piece.txt)` is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) and will work only in some shells.

I'm not sure of what is in `piece.txt`. Maybe you could do something like:

```
os.system("echo $(cat piece.txt) | nc 127.0.0.1 9988")
```

Maybe it's possible to use [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) as well:

```
os.system("nc 127.0.0.1 9988 < piece.txt")
```

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with something like this -